# How to get last index number of a value if multiple values are matching in an array?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an array with following values:

> [ram, shyam, Ravi, Ravi, Ravi, Rishi]

I want to get the index no of each string such that if there is a matching string get the last matching string index.

e.i. from the above array if search "ravi", output should give me index number is. "4".

Here is my code:

```
Object[] cars = { "Volvo", "Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda" };
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(cars[i].lastIndexOf("Volvo"));
    }
}
```

Output: 
0
0
-1
-1
-1

Comment: Just start looking from the end of the list, not from the beginning.

Comment: Print `i` value inside for loop if value matched.

Comment: @SatyaTNV that is not finding the last index. That is just printing multiple numbers.

Comment: @OP: you are currently not even checking there is a matching ``String``

Comment: Do you have to implement this functionality yourself, like for an assignment or a homework? If not, have a look at the answer given by @HaykMelqonyan.

Answer (score 4):

`List.indexOf()`

*Returns the index of the **first** occurrence of the specified element
      in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.*

`List.lastIndexOf()`

*Returns the index of the **last** occurrence of the specified element
      in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element*

**UPDATE**
for *case insensitive* filter

```
    List<String> cars = Arrays.asList("Volvo", "Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda");
    int resultIndex = -1;
    for (int i = cars.size()-1; i >=0; i--) {
        if (cars.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("volvo")) {
            resultIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(resultIndex);
```

output 
`1`

Comment: String[] cars = { "Volvo", "Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda" };
  for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(cars[i].lastIndexOf("Volvo"));
  }
 }

Comment: @hrishikeshbasak you dont need loop in here.
`List<String> cars = Arrays.asList("Volvo", "Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda");
  System.out.println(cars.lastIndexOf("Volvo"));`

Comment: @hrishikeshbasak welcome, I have updated also if you need to filter case insensitive .

Comment: Just to add any idea how to store WebElements as Arrays.asList()?
List<WebElement> listOfRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath()); 
List<List<WebElement>> all_elements_text = Arrays.asList(listOfRows);
this did not work

Comment: cannot undersatnd what does  this ?
`List<List<WebElement>> all_elements_text = Arrays.asList(listOfRows)`
you have already a list of elements 
` List<WebElement> listOfRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath());` 
just use `lisOfRows`

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet might help you to get what you want.

Important: call `lastIndexOf()` on the `List` and not on the String!

```
List<String> test=new ArrayList<String>();
test.add("a");
test.add("b");
test.add("a");
test.add("c");
test.add("a");

System.out.println("index is"+ test.lastIndexOf("a"));
```

**Expected output**: 4 (because "a" is on position 0, 2 and 4)

Answer (score 0):

Hayk's answer is great.

In case you would like to have more adjustable way of matching you could also use this (, because from the question it looks like you want case insensitive match maybe?):

```
IntStream.range(0, input.length)
    //      .filter(ix -> input[ix].compareToIgnoreCase(pattern) == 0) // ignore case matching
          .filter(ix -> input[ix].contains(pattern)) // substring matching        
          .reduce((a, b) -> b) // get last element
          .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Not found"));
```

Comment: yes it is case insensitive, because my array list will be always unique having duplicate values.

Comment: Right then uncommenting `.filter(ix -> input[ix].compareToIgnoreCase(pattern) == 0)` and removing the other filter should give you what you need

Answer (score 0):

Use map, key will be string and value will be index. Like:

```
Object[] cars = { "Volvo", "Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda" };
Map<String, Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    map.put(cars[i],i);
}
```

Here it will update last index of every string.
use `map.get("Volvo");` to get index of `Volvo`.